# PhoneGap - Can't download from website

Tags: cordova

I am trying to download any version from the Archive but none of them seem to work.

http://phonegap.com/install/

Anyone has a link where I can get them

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any trouble downloading from the link you provided...however, you could try the official Apache archive: http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/